# C++ Generating random vector

Tags: c++, vector, random

I'm just starting out, trying to learn to program. So I'm programming in C++ for now, and I tried to create a function that will generate a vector of random integers based on the parameters. So my function so far looks like this:

```
std::vector<int> GenerateRandomVector(int NumberCount,int minimum, int maximum) {
    std::vector<int> vecRandomValues;
    int i = 0, randValue = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (i < NumberCount) {
        randValue = rand() % maximum + minimum;
        vecRandomValues.push_back(randValue);
        i++;
    }
    return vecRandomValues;
}
```

So, my problem is that it does not respect the minimum and maximum value I give it, and also most of the time, 40% of the generated numbers are 0. I cannot figure out what I did so wrong here, nor do I have any idea on how to fix it. I'm using Clion on Windows 10.

Comment: Use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) (or [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)) together with the C++ [standard pseudo-random classes and objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) (like [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)).

Comment: By the way to generate a random number between a range you should do `% (maximum - minumum)` (possibly `+ 1` if the interval is closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation for the range is wrong.

```
randValue = rand() % (maximum - minimum + 1) + minimum;
```

Comment: I replaced that in my function. I called GenerateRandomVector(10 ,1 ,50) and this is the result I got: "0
15728832
2004570320
436207642
-1023409981
2004570320
0
0
21
37"

Comment: @MichaelBridge... did you add `return` in front of this code?

Comment: @MichaelBridge How are you printing that out?

Comment: I'm creating a local vector newVec = GenerateRandomVector(10, 1, 50) and then using a simple for loop to print it out.

Comment: @MichaelBridge Look carefully at what you've done there (before you went and editted your comment !!!). You have a bug. `i` is an item of the vector, not an index. You want `std::cout << i << "\n";

Comment: It worked... My mistake... Sorry for wasting so much of your time for such a trivial thing :(

Answer (score 8):

To expand upon @Some programmer dude's comment:

```
std::vector<int> GenerateRandomVector(int NumberCount,int minimum, int maximum) {
    std::random_device rd; 
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // these can be global and/or static, depending on how you use random elsewhere

    std::vector<int> values(NumberCount); 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(minimum, maximum);
    std::generate(values.begin(), values.end(), [&](){ return dis(gen); });
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Well, I called GenerateRandomVector(10, 1, 50) and yet again a bunch of the results are 0, and other are not respecting the limtis (i got 2004570320)

Comment: I'm not seeing anything unexpected when I try it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8001c047f156079)

Comment: Yea got my mistake, It was a very stupid mistake, as when I used the for loop to print it I used to get the value in the for loop as an index not as the actual value. I'm sorry for wasting your time, but now at least I know the method you showed too, so thanks for that :)

Comment: @MichaelBridge **That** is why we ask for a [mcve].  If you had given us that, we could have pointed out the obvious error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to all this, and to StackOverflow. Haven't gotten around to reading all the "best practices" so to say. I will definitely be sure to read all the proper stuff before posting anything else. Thank you :)

Comment: I'd change the comment (and implementation): "these *should* be static and/or global". It's always better to initialize those generators only once.

Comment: @MichaelBridge "Haven't gotten around to reading all the best practises" ... but you thought it reasonable to waste our time with a poorly written question?

Comment: @Bob__ I don't think implicit dependancies should be *encouraged*, but for things like random generators it's less bad. "can" is appropriate advice absent context